# How to create global filter in angularjs for different modules

Tags: angularjs

I have Module1 and Module2. I need to write common filter for both module. So how to create global filter so I will used in both modules. Please find below sample code

```
    //module One with Filter
var Module1 = angular.module("Module1App", []);
Module1.filter('makeUppercase', function () {
    return function (item) {
        return item.toUpperCase();
    };
});

//Module two with filter
var Module2 = angular.module("Module2App", []);
Module2.filter('makeUppercase', function () {
    return function (item) {
        return item.toUpperCase();
    };
});
```

Comment: A seperate module for filters and than add that module as a dependency to both modules, that would be my personal approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a third global module where you define the filter:

```
angular
    .module("GlobalModule", [])
    .filter('makeUppercase', function () {
        return function (item) {
            return item.toUpperCase();
        };
    });
```

Then use it in the other 2 modules. To do that, inject the `GlobalModule` and use its filter where needed:

```
angular.module("Module1App", ["GlobalModule"]);
angular.module("Module2App", ["GlobalModule"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a global module That include filter and inject that module to app modules

```
var global= angular.module("globalModule", []);
global.filter('makeUppercase', function () {
    return function (item) {
        return item.toUpperCase();
    };
});
```

inject global module to app modules

```
var Module1 = angular.module("Module1App", ["globalModule"]);

//Module two with filter
var Module2 = angular.module("Module2App", ["globalModule"]);
```